# Aligning content alongside an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position text vertically centered next to an image.

At the same time I don't want the text to overflow outside the vertical bounds of the image.

Struggling. Are there any best practices or tips?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="storiesblock">
  <p><a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/92x64/000000/fff">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </a>

<p><a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/92x64/000000/fff">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</a>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#storiesblock {
  width: 600px;
}
```

and, in ASCII art, what I'm trying to achieve:

```
IMAGEIMAGEIMAGE
IMAGEIMAGEIMAGE Text here...
IMAGEIMAGEIMAGE

IMAGEIMAGEIMAGE Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
IMAGEIMAGEIMAGE Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
IMAGEIMAGEIMAGE Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
```

where any additional text is hidden in the third block.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpWJGx

Comment: You could accomplish this with `flexbox` if you can use it in your project.

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/9p1wzf3c/ or http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/yjs3dtx4/?

Comment: No, I can't unfortunately.

Comment: Can we change up the HTML structure?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/fqn91pyr/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="storiesblock">
  <a href="#" class="story">
    <img class="story-image" src="http://dummyimage.com/92x64/000000/fff">
    <div class="copy">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="story">
    <img class="story-image" src="http://dummyimage.com/92x64/000000/fff">
    <div class="copy">
      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#storiesblock {
  width: 600px;
}

.story {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.copy {
  align-self: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.story-image {
  width: 92px;
  height: 64px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/RyanWarner/pen/yNbWPZ

Comment: Is it possible for the text to wrap until it fills the height of the block and then be cut off with an ellipsis?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#storiesblock {
display:inline-block;
  padding-right:5px;
}
#storiesblock2 {
  width: 300px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  max-height:64px;
}
```

```html
<div id="storiesblock"><a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/92x64/000000/fff"></div><div id="storiesblock2">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</a></p>
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using flexbox but you said you couldn't use it so I made a solution using the float and lineheight properties. It is a little messy and is unfortunately requires you to set different line heights for the two classes which could be annoying. I made a pen here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNWaMw

HTML

```
    <div id="storiesblock" class="cf">
  <div class="left-image">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/92x64/000000/fff" >  
  </div>
  <div class="right-text">
    <p><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="storiesblock" class="cf">
  <div class="left-image">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/92x64/000000/fff" >  
  </div>
  <div class="right-text long">
    <p><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  #storiesblock {
  width: 600px;
}

.left-image {
  float:left;
}

.right-text {
  float:left;
  height:64px;
  margin:0;
  width:508px;
  line-height:64px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.right-text.long {
  line-height:22px;
}

p {
  margin:0;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

You cannot use padding to achieve it as it will result in the overflow hidden not applying, and margin will push the whole block down.

I hope this helps you, let me know if you have any more specific questions.